# Magento 2 Google recaptcha js load failed

Tags: magento2, recaptcha

Recently installed a demo, found Google recaptcha loading error, and open sometimes normal and sometimes wrong,
I tried it many times and still can't solve it. Have any friends encountered this problem, how to solve it.

GET https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=globalOnRecaptchaOnLoadCallback&render=explicit net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=globalOnRecaptchaOnLoadCallback&render=explicit
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not specifically about magento. Stackoverflow might give you more result.